# Compare files using robocopy in for loop

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, robocopy

**Problem I want to solve:**
Compare files in one directory to files in a subdirectory. If they match, delete the file in the top directory. This is for Windows and I would like to use Windows Batch commands. If the file doesn't exist, the script will exit.

For example:
c:\temp contains baz_foo.exe
c:\temp\bar contains foo.exe

Attempt to copy foo.exe to c:\temp\bar, but robocopy notices they're the same, so it will exit and give a return code of 0. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/deploymentguys/2008/06/16/robocopy-exit-codes/

pseudo code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET ARCHIVEDIR=c:\temp\bar

FOR %%F in ('*baz_foo*.exe') DO SET (
    ROBOCOPY . %ARCHIVEDIR% %%F

if errorlevel 0 goto nocopy
if errorlevel 1 goto copy

:nocopy
echo Files are identical
goto exit

:copy
echo files different
goto exit

)

:exit
Call nextfile.bat
```

Clarification:
Note, I don't need the files copied to bar, I just want to know if they're the same or different. If it's the same, delete from c:\temp and move onto the next file; at the end of finding all files, call a different script.

Comment: Well, @w32sh, the `/MOV[E]` option does delete from source; or, you could swap source and target and use `/PURGE`...

Comment: `robocopy` supports an `/L` that lists files that would be copied without, perhaps you find this useful...

Comment: I suggest to correct your sample because robocopy would ***not*** notice `c:\temp\baz_foo.exe` to be equal to `c:\temp\bar\foo.exe`.

Comment: Just to clarify: if a file exists in the top-folder but not in the sub-folder, do you want to leave it in the top-folder? i.e. you only want to delete the file in the top-folder if it exists in the sub-folder? OR do you only want to delete it from the top-folder if the sub-folder contains a newer version? or will they always be the same version? Why do both of your options `GOTO` exit? It will always exit regardless of what it's doing if it's laid out like that. I'll give an example answer and edit based on your response.

Comment: If the file exists in both locations, I would like it to be deleted from both locations. If it doesn't exist in the sub folder, keep the file in the top level folder.

Comment: alright, I've edited the answer to have a nested set of parentheses in the `if not errorlevel 1` section; it will now delete both files (one from each location) if they are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the [FC](https://ss64.com/nt/fc.html) command will work better here if you're just trying to compare files; coupled with an `if exist` in your loop. Will likely look something like this:

```
@echo off

set "top=c:\temp"
set "sub=%top%\bar"

for /r "%sub%" %%A in (*) do (
    if exist "%top%\%%~nxA" fc "%%A" "%top%\%%~nxA" > nul
    if not errorlevel 1 (
        del /f /q "%top%\%%~nxA"
        del /f /q "%%A"
    )
)

Call nextfile.bat
```

This looks at all files in `c:\temp\bar` and assigns each to parameter `%%A`; for each loop iteration it sees if the filename (including the extension; `%%~nxA`) of parameter `%%A` exists in `c:\temp` - and if it does, it compares the files with `FC` and outputs that to `nul` so it doesn't display the results in your window. After that, it determines the `errorlevel` - I used `if not errorlevel 1` here so it would only apply to files that are the same, since sometimes `errorlevel 0` will give you a false positive in this situation without some tweaking. If it passes this test, it will delete those matching files from both `c:\temp` and `c:\temp\bar`. It's true that there are other possible `errorlevels` beyond `0` and `1` for `FC` (can be `-1` or `2`), but the for-loop already establishes that it can't be `2` since the files have to exist in both directories for it to do anything, and `-1` is also mostly ruled out for the same reasons. Hopefully this accomplishes what you are looking for - just leave a comment if I am misunderstanding what your requirements are.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. FC is a better idea, I wasn't aware of it.

Comment: @RegisteredUser happy to help!